# Pear install for macports PHP5

Tags: php, pear, macports

I have PHP5 installed via macports in /opt/local/..the default location for macports. There's no portfile for pear. If I do a standard pear install from the pear site what directory location should pear be placed in to work with PHP?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While the curl option works, it won't update as you update your ports.  An alternative:

```
sudo port install php5 +pear
```

This will install the variant of php5 with pear, in the same location as downloading above, and it will update as you update macports.

Comment: don't forget to use pear config-set to change your config variables to the macports /opt/local directories!

Comment: I had it installed but wasn't activated [List ports]  sudo port installed php5  [Activate port]    sudo port activate php5 @5.x.x_x+apache2+pear

Comment: Successfully installed PEAR via this command and config settings were set to opt/local/... directories. However, I still get back `No releases available for package XXX` from any install commands!

Comment: Updated my etc/php.ini to `include_path = ".:/opt/local/lib/php"` plus a restart fixes the problem.

Comment: Something to beware of is that the php5 port will not install the most recent version of PHP available. As I type this, it will install PHP 5.3.something, which has been EOLed by the PHP project, whereas 5.4 and 5.5 are available by installing the php54 and php55 ports respectively - unfortunately, neither currently have +pear variants and I haven't figured out yet if there's a MacPorts way to get Pear installed under them (5.4 in my case).

Comment: @GarrettAlbright: Have you figured out a solution to that for 5.5? I opened a question but haven't found an answer yet: http://superuser.com/q/650299/39309

Comment: Matt, I *did* end up figuring it out (for 5.4, at least), and have posted an answer to your question.

Comment: port search pear | grep php54

there is a pear package for 5.4 now, it is separate though.

Comment: UPDATE: The variants are now separate packages (e.g. php55-pear, php55-mysql). The php55-pear port seems to be broken, at least....

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue just now, and went for installing PEAR in exactly the directory you mentioned.

```
curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
sudo php go-pear.phar
```

I changed the installation base directory ($prefix) to point to /opt/local and ran the installer.  It amended my php.ini file to include the PEAR path.

My bash path already contained /opt/local/bin, so PEAR just worked!

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why nobody wrote an updated solution, so I do it:

```
sudo port install pear-PEAR
sudo port install php53-pear
```

Replace `53` with whatever version of PHP you want to use. Then install the pear-package you need with MacPorts! You can get a full list of available packages with

```
port echo name:^pear-
```

As mentioned in a comment of the other answer, go here for more info:
https://superuser.com/q/650299/39309

Answer (score 0):

For those of you running PHP outside of MacPorts @Ben's answer, with the following modification, is actually the solution to the problem. I needed PEAR to install PHPUnit so I could do some unit testing but I use XAMPP.

I followed Ben's solution but got an error when trying to install it. My error was:

```
WARNING! The include_path defined in the currently used php.ini does 
not contain the PEAR PHP directory you just specified:
</opt/local/share/pear>
If the specified directory is also not in the include_path used by
your scripts, you will have problems getting any PEAR packages working.

Current include path           : .:
Configured directory           : /opt/local/share/pear
Currently used php.ini (guess) :
```

I set the path of ***Currently used php.ini*** to the following and all worked perfectly:

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini`

Hope that at worst, this helps other XAMPP users!