# Installing PHP PEAR code sniffer (mac)

Tags: php, pear, phpcodesniffer

Attempting to install the PHP PEAR code sniffer extension on a mac (after installing Mac Ports) to no avail. Ultimate goal is Drupal code sniffing in Komodo somewhat via these instructions... http://blog.8bitplateau.net/drupa-code-sniffer-komodo/

**Command:**

```
pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
```

**Error:**

> No releases available for package "pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer"

Comment: Presumably this can be solved over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981134/pear-install-for-macports-php5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needed to update my php.ini for `include_path = ".:/opt/local/lib/php"`

Answer (score 5):

After downloading:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
```

I was getting package unavailable when tyring to install the package.
My answer, working in Windows, from the command prompt type:

```
pear clear-cache
```

then type:

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

job done, if you clear the cache after every installation, any further install goes without a hitch. ENjoy

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command and it worked:

```
sudo pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
```

Comment: Bascially: `sudo !!`